# Slanger: Could not find key

Tags: javascript, python

I've setup my slanger server correctly. It runs but when I connect from the browser it complains about the app key not being found? but my app_key and key are the same...

I send events like so in python

```
p = pusher.Pusher(app_id='mysite', key='mysite', secret='secretstuff', host='slanger.mysite.com', port='4567')
```

I run the slanger server like this:

```
slanger -k mysite -s secretstuff
Running Slanger v.0.4.0

Slanger API server listening on port 4567
Slanger WebSocket server listening on port 8080
```

This is what the browser outputs

> WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://slanger.mysite.com:8080/app/mysite?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.2.3&flash=false'
>   failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
>   pusher.min.js:12 Pusher : Error :
>   {"type":"WebSocketError","error":{"type":"PusherError","data":{"code":4001,"message":"Could
>   not find app by key mysite. Perhaps you're connecting to the wrong
>   cluster."}}}

here's my JS code:

```
    Pusher.host = 'slanger.mysite.com'
    Pusher.app_id = 'mysite'
    Pusher.ws_port = 8080
    Pusher.wss_port = 8080

    var pusher = new Pusher('mysite');
    var channel = pusher.subscribe("test");

    channel.bind('update', function (data) {
        console.log(data.message);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you forgot to add wsHost config option.
I got the same issue as you, and this worked for me.

Following slanger documentation, you should do it like this:

```js
Pusher.host   = 'slanger.example.com'
Pusher.port   = 4567

var pusher = new Pusher('#{Pusher.key}', {
  wsHost: "0.0.0.0",
  wsPort: "8080",
  wssPort: "8080",
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'flash']
});
```